# Where does RACK log to?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I am running a sinatra app through RACK.

To which file does the activity get logged ? Also how can I set the log file path ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends. Many developers define their app log file to app/servername.log or just to the current path where the Rack app is loaded.

Yes you can change it's path.

Usually you get a config.ru file with something like:

```
    log = File.new("sinatra.log", "a+")
    $stdout.reopen(log)
    $stderr.reopen(log)

    # optionally to sync logs while the server is running
    $stderr.sync = true
    $stdout.sync = true
```

and/or

```
    configure do
      LOGGER = Logger.new("sinatra.log")
      enable :logging, :dump_errors
      set :raise_errors, true
    end
```

in this case the log file is located under appdir/sinatra.log. But remember this code can be anywhere in your Rack app, so please seek for "log" in your application directory.

```
    $ cd projectname
    $ grep -ri 'log' *
```

have fun and post here your config.ru and/or the mainprojectfile.rb.

Comment: Hi Francisco.

Yep, this worked perfect for me.

log_path = "<path-to-log-file>"
LOGGER = Logger.new(log_path, "daily")
log = File.new(log_path, "a+")
STDOUT.reopen(log)
STDERR.reopen(log)

Comment: @include: Is there a way that I can make the production and development envirnments log to files but make test log to the terminal? It seems that when I reopen `$stdout` and `$stderr`, it redirects test output to files also.

Comment: Reopening STDOUT can make Passenger to not start: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems

Answer (score 1):

The line of `LOGGER = Logger.new("sinatra.log")` in [@include's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367815/2658159) did not work for me.

However, an alternative listed [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/12/production-logging-sinatra/) (along with some helpful explanations) worked for me, tested with ruby 2.5.3 and sinatra 2.0.1.

For additional info, that alternative is based on the structure presented in a [Sinatra recipe](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/middleware/rack_commonlogger).

Answer (score -2):

The `object_id` are initially the same but it's better to assign to `$stderr`. That also leaves you open to return the stream to where it was originally with `STDERR`:

```
 $ irb
>> $stderr.object_id == STDERR.object_id
=> true
```

Same object, for now. Send it elsewhere,

```
>> $stderr = File.open('/tmp/foo', 'w')
=> #<File:/tmp/foo>
>> $stderr.puts "Uh-oh, foo"
=> nil
>> $stderr.flush    # if you want to verify its output
=> #<File:/tmp/foo>
>> $stderr.object_id == STDERR.object_id
=> false
```

`$stderr` and `STDERR` refer to different objects. `STDERR` still streams to the terminal here,

```
>> STDERR.puts "Uh-oh, original STDERR"
Uh-oh, original STDERR
=> nil
```

Restore `$stderr`,

```
>> $stderr = STDERR
=> #<IO:0x106fddb88>
>> $stderr.object_id == STDERR.object_id
=> true
```

And we're back!